# How to design a code annotation tool for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, user-interface

We are currently working on a research project on how to turn community knowledge into AI. We would like to extend the current Stack Overflow UI with annotation tools for given text and code examples. For instance, this would allow users to annotate flawed statements and bugs within code snippets attached to a question. Our current framework would be able to learn from the annotated code, how certain bugs look like and how to fix them.

We are generally interested what the community thinks about this idea, if you consider it as helpful and whether you have suggestions for other use cases.

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. Please elaborate who are you.